# About java generic inheritance type error

Tags: java, spring-boot, generics

1. I wrote a generic base class Controller。

```
public abstract class BaseController<T extends BaseService<
        R_ID_REQUEST,
        PAGE_SEARCH_REQUEST,
        PAGE_RESULT,
        ONE_RESULT,
        SAVE_REQUEST
        >,
        R_ID_REQUEST,
        PAGE_SEARCH_REQUEST,
        PAGE_RESULT,
        ONE_RESULT,
        SAVE_REQUEST>{

    @Autowired
    protected T service;

    @PostMapping("/save")
    public Serializable doSave(@RequestBody @Valid SAVE_REQUEST save) {
        return service.doSave(save);
    }

    // plase look me
    @PostMapping("/delete")
    public Serializable doSelectOne(@RequestBody @Valid R_ID_REQUEST delete) {
        return service.doDelete(delete);
    }
```

2.Other Controllers only need to inherit it, like this.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/admin")
public class AdminController extends BaseController<AdminService, RequiredOneParamRequest<Long>, AdminListRequest, IPage<AdminVo>, AdminVo, AdminSaveRequest> {

//  @Override
//  public AdminVo doSelectOne(@RequestBody @Valid RequiredOneParamRequest<Long> one) {
//      return super.doSelectOne(one);
//  }
```

3.But the generic field type in RequiredOneParamRequest one is integer,this is debugger value

4.An error will be reported when getting the value in the service

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
    at com.jasolar.auth.center.server.service.AdminService.doSelectOne(AdminService.java:88)
    at com.jasolar.auth.center.server.service.AdminService.doSelectOne(AdminService.java:33)
```

5.But, If I override the parent class method, there will be no exception。

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/admin")
public class AdminController extends BaseController<AdminService, RequiredOneParamRequest<Long>, AdminListRequest, IPage<AdminVo>, AdminVo, AdminSaveRequest> {

@Override
    public AdminVo doSelectOne(@RequestBody @Valid RequiredOneParamRequest<Long> one) {
        return super.doSelectOne(one);
    }
```

6.do again

end.

I don't know why there is such a result。

springboot version 2.2.10.RELEASE
jdk version 1.8.271